# How to to retrieve sections on a YouTube channel using the API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Kindly look at the 2 sections (from "TheEllenShow" YouTube channel) in the image - "guest interviews, season 12" and "adorable kids": [image: image showing 2 sections -]

I would like to programmatically retrieve all the names of the sections and also the list of videos under each section.

Is this possible? Is each section considered a "playlist"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Each section is, as you thought, a playlist. You can get all the playlists for the channel using the [Playlists:List](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list) call:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet&channelId=UCp0hYYBW6IMayGgR-WeoCvQ&maxResults=50&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

The `channelId` above (`UCp0hYYBW6IMayGgR-WeoCvQ`) is for 'TheEllenShow'.

To get the videos in each playlist you will need to call [PlaylistItems:List](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) with the `playlistID` parameter set to the ids that you got from the first call. For example the 'Guest Interviews - Season 13' id is `PLuW4g7xujBWeQIhuZIqshnbbhidiTHysJ`:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&playlistId=PLuW4g7xujBWeQIhuZIqshnbbhidiTHysJ&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Comment: I've up voted your answer, but it would be helpful to include how you can get all the Channel sections from the Channel ID, and then subsequently retrieve all the playlists or arrays of playlists corresponding to each channel section. The documentation is poor, but it is not clear if EVERY channel section will include either a playlist or playlist[]. For example, the "Uploads" section doesn't seem to point to a Playlist.

Answer (score 1):

After more research, what I was referring to are called "channel sections"... They are described as follows:

> Channel sections are a great way to organize and promote content you
>   create and content created by others that you wish to curate and
>   highlight on your channel home tab. There can be a maximum of 10
>   sections on your channel home tab. Sections can be created from a
>   single existing playlist (created by you or someone else), a group of
>   playlists, or a group of channels.

See: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/3027787?hl=en

You can retreive these sections programmatically using ChannelSections: list. More info is here:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channelSections/list